# How to show that $\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> Show that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 0$$

I know that I have to use the squeeze theorem, but I'm unable to create a situation where I have a situation where the limit of the function in question is between zeroes.

I'm also thrown off by the fact that $\sqrt{1} = 1$ and $\sqrt{1} = -1$ and am not sure how to evaluate the square root of that when attempting the problem.

edit: This question was written as I wrote it in my textbook. It's possible that the answer that I was supposed to come up with was that the limit does in fact not exist.

Comment: that limit does not exist. by squaring both side you can see it

Comment: $\sqrt1=-1$????

Comment: While $1$ has two square roots, the notation $\sqrt{1}$ means the positive square root  of $1$ and thus $\sqrt{1}=1$ by definition.

Comment: The statement in the title of your question is not true. Please check your question to make sure it is correct.

Comment: One can easily see the limit in your question is not true by contradiction: if it was true then $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\cdot 0=0$, which is not true since  $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\cos x$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function oscillates so wildly that it would not have a limit as $x \to 0$. Here is a graphical plot that confirms this, between the points $\pm 0.01$:

[image]

Such wild oscillation typically occurs, because $\cos x$ is a periodic function with period $2\pi$, which means $\cos(\frac 1{x^2})$ moves vary fast towards infinity as $x \to 0$, and therefore oscillates wildly, since you now require $x$ to change very little, to go from one period to the next.

Having a  function to curb the oscillations of $\cos \frac 1{x^2}$ would help formation of the limit. However, $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ does not even go to zero! It goes to $1$, and therefore does absolutely nothing to curb the oscillations. You need something that goes to zero, so that this cosine function has no time to oscillate. Such an example is provided by the function $x\cos(\frac 1{x^2})$, whose graph I urge you to see below:

[image]

Here, you can actually apply the squeeze theorem, and be able to conclude that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $x_n=\dfrac 1{\sqrt{n\pi}}\to 0$ when $n\gg 1$.

Then $f(x_n)=\sqrt{1+\frac 1{n\pi}}\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n\sqrt{1+\frac 1{n\pi}}$

And $f(x_{2n})\to 1$ while $f(x_{2n+1})\to -1$ thus $f$ cannot have a limit in zero.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your  limit exist let say

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \ell$$
Then by squaring both side  we get that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(1+x^2)\cdot \cos^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \ell^2$$

But      since $0\le \cos^2u\le 1$ we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}x^2\cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \le   \lim_{x \to 0}x^2 =0$$
Thus the previous line before becomes

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = \ell^2$$
which impossible. since this limit does not exists. therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{1+x^2} \cdot \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $$ does not exist.